Linux breaking my NTFS filesystems?
I'm currently using Kubuntu 22.04, kernel 6.5.0-28 amd64.
Ever since the unassisted update, my system has been stuttering a lot. Initially I thought it was the RAM, but then I noticed that the system would completely freeze if I tried to open my extra NTFS drive, the same happens if I tried to save a file to it.
My first guess was that the HD was going bad, and my worries were confirmed after a reboot, where the filesystem would fail to mount.  I couldn't even see the partitions in it. I attempted formatting it, but It also failed.  I accepted the loss and replaced the drive with an SSD, also formatted to NTFS.
It worked fine for a while, but then it too became inaccessible after just a few days, luckily I was able to reformat it, I choose EXT4 this time, and it seems to be fine again and working perfectly for a week already.
Now I'm wondering if the operating system is somehow breaking my NTFS file systems for some reason but I have no expertise to make proper tests to verify the cause.

"Couldn't even see partitions" already rules out a filesystem issue, but, Which Linux NTFS driver are you using? What does the Windows chkdsk tool say about the filesystems once they stop working?

Looks like It's using ntfs-3g. and yea, I tried to run chkdsk, and it didn't work, even the partition table was gone.

I've run ntfs under linux and I've never had data loss, and generally its been really good about telling me what's wrong. generally if its uncleanly mounted on windows, a drive can go inaccessible, but trying to mount it would tell you

Hopefully, you've not mounted a "dirty" Windows NTFS volume for writing in the past. See https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/ntfs-3g.8.html  about Fast Boot and Hibernation.

Regardless of OS:s you need to make sure the filesystem is in a clean state when you move disk between OS:es. --- i.e. save all data, unmount always (Eject!), do not "hibernate" as that involves trickery.
